# There's any report system for Django 1.6 and Python 3?

Tags: django, python-3.x, report

I found the Geraldo Report, but it's not compatible with Django 1.6 and Python 3.

And I don't want to make a HTML page, to print in PDF, because I need to control headers, sumary etc..

Here is my question: there is any report for django with python 3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReportLab 3.0 it's compatible with Python 3.3 http://www.reportlab.com/software/documentation/relnotes/30/

There's a section in the documentation for this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/outputting-pdf/